# How do I get my collision function into my private void Update() on Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have  object 1 with rigid body and box collider, I want it to hit object 2 (also has collider and rigid body) so I can use the collision to stop object 1 for 5 seconds then have it move through object 2 whish has kinematics on

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TRAINMOVE : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int speed = 200;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       
        StartCoroutine(WaitBeforeMove());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
 private  void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }
   private  void Update()
    {
       
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
      
        


    }
    //void OnCollision(Collision stop)
   // {
    //    if (stop.gameObject.name == "train trigger station1") 
    //    {
    //        speed = 0;
   //         WaitBeforeMove();
   //         speed = 200;
   //         rb.AddForce(transform.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);


  //      }
  //      else
  //     {
  //          speed = 200;
  //      }
  // }
   IEnumerator WaitBeforeMove()
  {
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not exactly how [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) work.

1. The method/message you are looking for is called [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html). If it is not exactly written like that and with the expected signature then Unity doesn't find it and never invokes it.
2. A [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) does **not** delay the outer method which runs/starts it.
3. A [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) has to be started using [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) otherwise it does nothing (or at least it only runs until the first `yield` statement).

   ```
   private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision stop)
   {
       if (stop.gameObject.name == "train trigger station1") 
       {
           StartCoroutine(WaitBeforeMove());
       }
   }

   private IEnumerator WaitBeforeMove()
   {
       speed = 0;
       // Note that without this you would have no force applied but still the remaining velocity it already has
       rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
       speed = 200;
   }
   ```
4. The method/message `OnCollisionEnter` can be a Courine itself! So in your specific case you actually can just do

   ```
   // By making this an IEnumerator Unity automatically starts it as a Coroutine!
   private IEnumerator OnCollisionEnter(Collision stop)
   {
       if (stop.gameObject.name == "train trigger station1") 
       {
           speed = 0;
           rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
           yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
           speed = 200;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Finally instead of permanently continue to add `0` force I would in general rather use a simple `bool` flag and pause the adding of force entirely.

   You should [`AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) not every frame but rather in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerLoop.FixedUpdate.html).

   And then you should **not** multiply force by `Time.deltaTime`. Since it is applied in fixed time intervals in `FixedUpdate` it is already a frame-rate independent event.

   ```
    private bool stopped;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(stopped) return;

        rb.AddForce(transform.up * speed);
    }

    // By making this an IEnumerator Unity automatically starts it as a Coroutine!
    private IEnumerator OnCollisionEnter(Collision stop)
    {
        if (stop.gameObject.name == "train trigger station1") 
        {
            stopped = true;
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
            stopped = false;
        }
    }
   ```
6. I suggest instead of comparing a name you should rather use a Tag and use [`stop.gameObject.CompareTag("Station")`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html)

Comment: I realized that I did not want to add zero force but instead and a bit of negative force so that it would slow down, would that work? also thanks

Comment: @KarlnicoDiego yes, then again use what you had like in point 4) .. except: I still would put the `AddForce` into the `FixedUpdate`

Comment: I got it to stop with rb.isKinematic = true;